# "left side of comma operator.." error in html content of render

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Its straightforward process;

Here is the origin render method I want it to be(I want my table outside of div):
[image]

but jsx compiler dont allow it for some reason?

but if i move the table inside of div element;
everything looks ok.
[image]

so only diff is place of table. **why jsx interfere this process ? why its necessary ?**

Answer (score 97, accepted):

In `JSX`, we can return only one `html` element from `return`, can't return multiple elements, if you want to return multiple elements then wrap all the html code in a `div` or by any other wrapper component.

Same thing is happening in your 1st case, you are returning 2 elements, one `div` and one `table`. when you are wrapping them in one `div` everything is working properly.

Same rule you have to follow for `conditional rendering` of components.

Example:

**Correct:**

```
{ 1==1 /* some condition */ ? 
    <div>
        True
    </div> 
: 
    <div>
        False
    </div>
}
```

**Wrong:**

```
{ 1==1 /* some condition */ ? 
    <div>
        True 1
    </div>
    <div>
        True 2
    </div> 
: 
    <div>
        False 1
    </div>
    <div>
        False 2
    </div>
}
```

Comment: didnt know that, it makes sense now ok.

Comment: In case of React, you can also use `React.Fragment` or `<> </>` shorthand.

Answer (score 30):

Just a quick update. If you are using React v16.2.0 and above you also can use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html).

```
  return (
    <>
        <div>
            True 1
        </div>
        <div>
            True 2
        </div> 
    </>
  );
```

I also replied to a similar question, more in depth [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50565558/2829540)

Answer (score 0):

Another cause of this error is accidentally ending your line with a comma instead of a semicolon, this might happen because you make a mistake during refactoring of your code.

These give errors

```
return <div>hi</div>, // error
return (<div>hi</div>,) // error
```

These are correct:

```
return <div>hi</div>; // ok
return (<div>hi</div>) // ok
return (<div>hi</div>); // ok
```

This error is more cofusing in this case, since it highlights the whole JSX block, instead of the comma

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the comma is interpreted as “comma operator” and not comma within arrays, objects, etc.

Comma operator evaluates each expression separated by comma and returns the last value.

```
const foo = (1, 2, 3) // returns 3
```

In this example, 3 will be assigned to foo. But it is highly likely that author thought (1, 2, 3) will be assigned like python tuple. So this error exists.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator

So if you encountered this error, chances are there are some mistakes in your array/object/etc and it is interpreted as "comma operator".

**Example code which causes this error.**

```
const foo = (expr) => {
  const bar = ""
  const baz = ""

  switch (expr) {
    case 'Oranges', 'Mangoes': // error, you can't use comma for switch
      break;
    case 'Papayas':
      break;
  }


  { bar, baz } // You forgot to write return. Javascript thinks this is comma operator.
}
```