# Returning multiple elements in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to return two links if the user is not logged in. Something like this:

```
<Nav>
    {if(this.state.user) {
        <NavItem onClick={this.logout}>Log out</NavItem>
    } else {
        <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Log in</NavItem>
        <NavItem onClick={this.register}>Register</NavItem>
    }
    }
</Nav>
```

I know I can do this with a ternary operator:

```
<Nav>
    {this.state.user ?
        <NavItem onClick={this.logout}>Log out</NavItem>
        :
        <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Log in</NavItem>
    }
</Nav>
```

The problem is I want to render the two NavItems. I saw I can do it with a function, but when I try to do it in a function like this:

```
myFunction(){
    return(
        <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
        <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
    )
}
```

It tells me that the second element is unreachable and breaks. So how can I return two elements? Stringifying the code doesn't help

Comment: jsx expects a wrapper element or an array.
So either try putting them in array...[<NavItem .../>, <NavItem.../>]
or with a wrapper. <div><NavItem .../><NavItem.../></div>

Comment: You want [`React.Fragment`](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you are using React v16.2.0 and above you can use the shorter version of Fragments

```
<>
 <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
 <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
</>
```

If you are using a version below React v16 you can only return one element in `jsx`, so you have to wrap your elements inside one:

```
<div>
 <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
 <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
</div>
```

If you are using React v16 and abose you can use [Fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html)

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

...
...

    <Fragment>
     <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
     <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
    <Fragment/>
```

You could also return an Array of Elements [as announced here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/09/26/react-v16.0.html#new-render-return-types-fragments-and-strings):

```
 return [
    <NavItem key="1" onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>,
    <NavItem key="2" onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
  ];
```

Depending on your environment you might not be able to use all of these solutions: [support for fragments](https://reactjs.org/blog/2017/11/28/react-v16.2.0-fragment-support.html#support-for-fragment-syntax)

Comment: Please add a mention about `<React.Fragment>` and I'll pick as best, as this answer incorporates most methods

Comment: Just want to point out that return an Array of Elements needs the keys! (As it is stated inside the link you shared)

Comment: @Tanckom the `key` prop is in the example. Is that what you are talking about?

Comment: @KevinAmiranoff I know but just wanted to point it out as it wont work otherwise (took me 10min to figure it out afterwards)

Answer (score 7):

In the lastest react version you can wrap them in an empty fragment:

```
<>
  <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
  <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Zaloguj się</NavItem>
</>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to wrap it around something, like `<div>` or `<React.Fragment>` (v16):

```
<React.Fragment>
  <NavItem onClick={this.login}>Log in</NavItem>
  <NavItem onClick={this.register}>Register</NavItem>
</React.Fragment>
```

You must use the ternary operators instead of `if` statements to directly render the elements in JSX.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Fragment in ReactJS which is available in React 16.

> which lets you group a list of children without adding extra nodes to
>   the DOM.

You can import fragment like below ,

> ```
> import React, {Fragment} from 'react';
> ```

```
  To render:


  <Fragment>
   <ChildA />
   <ChildB />
   <ChildC />
 </Fragment>
```

By using Fragment, you can avoid extra html element such div being rendered.

> For more info, you can refer https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html