# Multiple instances of react component: access prop

Tags: reactjs

I want to have two component that has different text and can pass different parameters to actions, but I want to reuse them.

I have the parent class "insurances", the relevant parts (imo) is this.

```js
render() {
  return (
    <InsuranceTypeCard
      type="HOUSEHOLD_GOODS"
      header="myThings"
    />
    <InsuranceTypeCard
      type="PRIVATE_LIABILITY"
      header="myDamages"
    />
  )
}
```

Now in the InsuranceTypeCard I use the props like this and it renders the types two times differently as intended but in the "Dialog" (popup from material-ui) it will render the just the second type two times, so it seems as they share the same props somehow and the second component overwrites the first instance.

```js
//insuranceTypeCard.tsx
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {this.props.type}
    </div>
    <Dialog>
      {this.props.type};
    </Dialog>
```

Comment: Can you even return sibling components in`React`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565468/returning-multiple-elements-in-jsx/50565558#50565558

Comment: I am surprised it did not throw errors but might be related.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';

// further down in your code...
render() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <InsuranceTypeCard
        type="HOUSEHOLD_GOODS"
        header="myThings"
      />
      <InsuranceTypeCard
        type="PRIVATE_LIABILITY"
        header="myDamages"
      />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

The `<Fragment>` component can be used when you're trying to render components side-by-side. However, it was only added in React 16.2, so if you're running a previous version, you can polyfill the functionality like so:

```
const Fragment = ({ children }) => children;

// the rest is the same
```

See if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But doesn't seem to change anything. The strange thing is that the first {this.props.type} gives back the correct different types but inside the dialog its not working anymore

Comment: For now I solved it by storing the name of the currently open dialog in the redux store and then mapStateToProps to a new prop.

Comment: @solaire That's really weird. You can check what props are being passed into your React components by using the React devtools extension available in Chrome/Firefox; see if that helps, maybe?