# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag error popping up even after enclosing the return statements within a parent element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner to react and I've been trying to understand the basis. I'm confused with the exact meaning of the error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Here's the code in which the error occurs.

```
function App() {
  const name = "john";
  const isNameShowing = false;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <h1>
          {isNameShowing ? (
            test
          ) : (
              <h1>test</h1>
              <h2>There is no name</h2>
          )}
        </h1>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I understand that the error part occurs here in this block

```
     <h1>
          {isNameShowing ? (
            test
          ) : (
              <h1>test</h1>
              <h2>There is no name</h2>
          )}
     </h1>
```

The error says I've to put self enclosing tags or a parent div element. But isn't it already enclosed within the main div element ?

Also isn't the below part of the code already enclosed within  the parent `<h1>` element around it?

```
          (
              <h1>test</h1>
              <h2>There is no name</h2>
          )
```

Inspite of having `<h1>` as a parent element and even if that doesn't suffice, and the main div element being the parent element, the error still pops up. What exactly does being wrapped around the parent element mean to prevent this error ?

Comment: you are trying to have an h1 inside an h1?

Comment: @cmgchess I've just been testing out different things since I'm a beginner. Also another thing that I noticed is this particular <h1> element inside another <h1> element produces a larger text than the usual <h1> element without having an <h1> as its parent. Any reasons for that ?

Comment: It's not valid HTML so the results are not guaranteed. You can always look up valid children for any element in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements) under 'Permitted content'. Take the time to learn valid syntax before trying to debug errors based on invalid input.

Comment: That being said returning multiple elements from a code block requires an intermediary parent so you would need `... : (<><h1>test</h1><h2>..</h2></>)}`, see: [Fragments](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment). Duplicate here: [Returning multiple elements in JSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565468/returning-multiple-elements-in-jsx)

Comment: @pilchard so it all comes down to <h1> not being a valid parent to tags like <h1>, <h2> etc, right ? By parent element, can you tell me which tags constitute as parents exactly in JSX, because I now came to know that not all tags classify as parent to some tags according to this example. In HTML though, block level elements can have block as well as inline level elements as their child and here <h1> is a block level element, to which its child another <h1> tag also being a block level element which is valid.

Comment: No, sorry if the order of my comments is confusing. The main issue is that you are trying to return two elements from a code block without an intermediary parent as per my second comment. Read the linked documentation on [fragments](https://react.dev/reference/react/Fragment) and the linked [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50565468/returning-multiple-elements-in-jsx) for details.